Encountering 400 BAD REQUEST Error in Flask App POST Request
I'm encountering a 400 BAD REQUEST error when running my Flask application. The error occurs when I send a POST request to http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict. The console logs show the following message:
POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict 400 (BAD REQUEST)
sendRequest @ script.js:3
onclick @ (index):13

Additionally, I see the following error in the console:
script.js:20 Error: Error: Server error: BAD REQUEST at script.js:12:19

Files Provided for Review:
1 app.py:
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, send_from_directory
from flask_cors import CORS
import logging
from transformers import TFGPT2LMHeadModel, GPT2Tokenizer
import os

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

# Load the GPT-2 model and tokenizer
model_name = "gpt2"
model = TFGPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained(model_name)
tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static')
CORS(app)

@app.route('/')
def serve_index():
    try:
        return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, 'index.html')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return jsonify({'error': 'index.html not found'}), 404

@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    try:
        data = request.get_json()
        print(f"Incoming request data: {data}")  # Log incoming data for debugging
        if not data:
            return jsonify({'error': 'No JSON data provided'}), 400
        text = data.get('text')
        if not text:
            return jsonify({'error': 'No text provided'}), 400

        # Generate a response using GPT-2 with attention mask
        max_length = 150  # Adjust as needed
        inputs = tokenizer.encode_plus(
            text,
            return_tensors='tf',
            padding='max_length',  # Use padding='max_length'
            truncation=True,
            max_length=max_length  # Crucial: Set max_length
        )
        input_ids = inputs['input_ids']
        attention_mask = inputs['attention_mask']
        outputs = model.generate(
            input_ids,
            attention_mask=attention_mask,
            max_length=max_length,
            num_return_sequences=1,
            pad_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id
        )
        response_text = tokenizer.decode(outputs[0], skip_special_tokens=True)
        logging.debug(f"Generated response: {response_text}")
        return jsonify({'response': response_text})
    except ValueError as e:
        logging.error(f"Input Error: {e}")
        return jsonify({'error': str(e)}), 400  # 400 Bad Request for input errors
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Model Error: {e}")
        return jsonify({'error': 'An error occurred during prediction'}), 500

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)  # Set debug=False for production
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Failed to start the Flask server: {e}")
        raise


script.js:

function sendRequest() {
    const textInput = document.getElementById('textInput').value;
    fetch('/predict', {  // Switch to port 5000
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ text: textInput })  // This is the JSON sent to Flask
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`Server error: ${response.statusText}`);
        }
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        document.getElementById('response').innerText = `Response: ${data.response}`;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        document.getElementById('response').innerText = `Error: ${error}`;
    });
}

I tried changing the port, used different browsers - reconfigured the network, disabled the firelwall but nothing works. Page loads fines, but errors out during POST request.

What is your log showing?

there are at least three parts of your backend code that return a 400 error - which one is triggered to send that error?
